# Java Runtime Exception: Unable to create lock manager

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

Hello when I run a script as root on unix shell it works, for example:

```
sh -x /opt/auto/wso2is/bin/wso2server.sh
```

However when I run it as a non root user I get the following error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.loadClass(Bootstrap.java:63)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:45)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create lock manager.
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.CarbonLauncher.launch(CarbonLauncher.java:115)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.launchCarbon(Main.java:163)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.main(Main.java:95)
    ... 6 more
```

What is causing this?

I have the following environment variables declared:

```
JRE_HOME=/usr/java/jre1.7.0_51 

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/root/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/opt/kde3/bin:/usr/lib/java/jre/bin:/usr/local/bin

JAVA_BINDIR=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin

JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51

JDK_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51 

JAVA_ROOT=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51
```

According to http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21600112,
I don't have correct permissions for a folder but how am I meant to know which one?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround that might be able to give you a hint on what are the files have been changed on the permission due to previous startup using root user account.

You may do a `du -skh /opt/auto/` using a non-root user account. You will get permission denied when it attempt to check on the files/folders that is belongs to the root user. Then you should execute `chown -R "<non-root-user>:<non-root-user> <file/folder>` on those file/folder.

Once you have changed the ownership of the files/folder, please try to start it up again (by executing /opt/auto/wso2is/bin/wso2server.sh). You should be able to get wso2carbon log printed. Study the log again and make further amendment on the file/folders which still having permission error.